# Required sample size in internal audit

Tags: sample-size

In applied literature about the required sample size such as ["Sampling for effective internal auditing"](https://m.isaca.org/chapters10/Lusaka/NewsandAnnouncements/Documents/SAMPLING-FOR-INTERNAL-AUDITORS%5B1%5D.pdf) we find formulas for the required sample size to detect a proportion of a feature or an error rate as (I cite and use the same variable names)
$$
n = \frac{C^2 \rho q}{P^2},
$$
where $n$ is the required sample size, $C$ is the confidence level, $P$ is some measure of precision, $\rho = 1-q$ is the expected error rate.

Where do these formulas from auditing come from? I understand that their origin must be some Binomial distribution consideration with normal approximation.

Is there a publication where these sample size requirements are derived in a rigorous mathematical way?
I find quite a few publications citing formulae as the above but what is a good source for at the same time a rigorous mathematical treatment and applications in audit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the literature for interal auditing, but this looks quite similar to Normal approximation/Wald confidence interval ([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval)) and was published in  
 Laplace, Pierre Simon (1812). Théorie analytique des probabilités (in French). p. 283.
For a newer article about some of its problems:
Brown, Lawrence D.; Cai, T. Tony; DasGupta, Anirban. Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion. Statist. Sci. 16 (2001), no. 2, 101--133. doi:10.1214/ss/1009213286. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213286

For a specific citation for Audits somebody else might be able to help.

The formula of the Normal approximation interval is as follows :
$$p=\hat{p}\pm z*\sqrt{\dfrac{p(1-p)}n} $$

if we subtract $\hat{p}$ and square afterwards we get:
$$(p-\hat{p})²=\dfrac{z^2 *p(1-p)}n $$

Now we solve for n:
$$n= \dfrac{z^2 *p(1-p)}{(p-\hat{p})²}  $$

This is exactly your formula. $z^2$ is $C^2$ and $(p-\hat{p})^2$ is $P^2$ in your equation

Comment: Thanks for this reference! Thus if I expect and error rate $p$ (e.g. $5\%$) and I want to detect differences on a sample with confidence related to the normal quantile $z$ (e.g. $95\%$ and $z = z_{0.95}$) and I tolerate some error $P = \hat{p}-p$ (e.g. $6\%-5\%$) then I need a sample size of $n$ as calculated above ... does this make sense?

Comment: @Ric yes that makes sense! However, i confused the name of the interval. It is the normal approximation interval. I changed it above and also edited the correct citations. You should note, that the approximation interval tends to be less reliable for small n or extreme high or low p. (see the see the Brown et al. article above). Therefore, your estimated n might also be unreliable in these cases.